# Setting Data Transformer for $ also makes input $ required

Tags: google-app-maker

If you set a data transformer for example: #formatNumber('$#.00')
It then requires you to also use the $ when doing input. Is there a way to not require the $?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to just omit the "$" from the format pattern:

## formatNumber('#.00')

Comment: Then the user wont see the "$" which is what is preferred. The user should see $100.00 and be able to enter 100 without validation requiring $100.00